# Probability of stopping smoking

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

thank you for taking the time to read my question.

> Suppose a smoker decides to stop smoking. We want to model using a recursive relation, the probability of him smoking on the $n$-th day, given $p_1$, probability of him smoking the first day.
>
> - If he doesn't smoke on the $n$-th day, the next day the probability of him not smoking is $90\%$
> - If he smokes on the $n$-th day, probability of him not smoking the next day is $20\%$
>
> **Questions:**
>
> - What is the correct way to model this "game", and is it correct to assume it's a Markov chain with 2 states?

What I tried that netted different answers: (don't know which one is the correct one)

I got $
T=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.8
\end{array}\right]
$ as a transition matrix, $Q$ is the characteristic polynomial.

$$Q(T) = T² - 1.7T +0.7I_2$$

therefore if we multiply by $P_n-2: P_n = 1.7P_{n-1} - 0.7P_{n-2}$

Total probability theorem:
$$p_{n+1} = 0.8p_n + 0.1(1-p_n)\implies p_{n+1}=.7p_n+.1$$

Comment: Seems like a contradiction in terms. You first say probabilities are in terms of $p_1$, his smoke *the first day*, and then express them in terms of him smoking on the $n$-th day?

Comment: Apologies, I think I miss-explained, what we have is the probability of n+1th day, depending on if he smoked or not on the n-th day, and we wanna model a formula that  we can calculate the probability of smoking or not on any given day given only p1, probability of him smoking the first day

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Can you express $p_n$ recursively in terms of $p_{n-1}$?

Comment: I've added more details to what I tried to do, Math isn't exactly my strongest point, apologies

Comment: Ok, so $p_{n+1}=.7p_n+.1$  which implies that $p_{n+1}=.7^2p_{n-1}+.1\times (1+.7)$ and so on.  Can you see how to get something of the form $p_{n+1}=.7^{n}p_1+A_n$ for suitable $A_n$?

Comment: Ah no no, my problem isn't finding Pn = f(P1). I was wondering how come the two methods I've tried I've gotten two different series. Probably should have clarified a bit more.

Comment: I'm wondering if using the transition matrix and characteristic polynomiale is wrong in this case, and why would it be? if that's a bit clearer

Comment: I really can't sort out what you are asking.  It seems that you have the recursions you need.  Why do you imagine that those two recursions are incompatible?  Check using some random value for $p_1$ to confirm that both recursions hold.  Or derive a closed form for $p_n$ and confirm that both hold.

Comment: I'm not sure how to confirm if both recursions hold, Can you help me confirm?

Answer (score 1):

The recursion $$p_n=1.7p_{n-1}-.7p_{n-2}$$ can be solved in closed form.  The characteristic polynomial has roots $.7, 1$  so the solution is $$p_n=A\times .7^n+B$$  for suitable $A,B$.

Now, $p_1$ is the (unspecified) initial probability.  the information we are given implies that $$p_2=.7p_1+.1\implies A\times .7^2+B=A\times .7^2+.7B+.1\implies B=\frac 13$$

Given that form, regardless of the values of $A$, we can easily check that $$.7p_{n-1}+.1=.7\times A\times .7^{n-1}+.7B+.1=A\times .7^n+B=p_n$$

whence the first recursion implies the second.

Should add, if we are just interested in the limiting value, $L$, of $p_n$, we can read it off from the second recursion. We get $$L=.7L+.1\implies L=\frac 13$$  or you can read it off from the closed form, noting that $.7^n\to 0$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I get the Transition Matrix as following,
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.8
\end{array}\right]
$$
I think we can get the **Stationary distribution**
$$
\pi \mathbf{P}=\pi
$$
By comparing this definition with that of an eigenvector we see that the two concepts are related and that
$$
\pi=\frac{e}{\sum_{i} e_{i}}
$$
is a normalized$\left(\sum_{i} \pi_{i}=1\right) $ multiple of a left eigenvector $e$ of the transition matrix  $\mathbf{P} \text { with an eigenvalue of } 1 $.
Then we get $\pi = [\frac 23,\,\frac 13]$

i.e. The probability of successful quitting is $\frac 23$ , the contrary is $\frac 13$ after sufficent large $n$ days aprroximately